# Laravel Voyager broken strings in relationship menu

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I am currently working on a Project using Laravel and the Voyager Admin Panel.
When I'm trying to add a relationship using the bread builder I get the following broken strings.

[Broken String 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pv7Z.png)

[Broken Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUOgJ.png)

After looking at the Voyager Views I have come to the conclusion that it is most likely a localization issue even though I'm using the English locale Settings. 
But i was still unable to fix it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I've already answer this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53663749/7128950).