# Laravel Voyager admin panel showing with broken link texts

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I've just installed Voyager admin panel and the link texts appear broken, like the picture:

[image]

[image]

My #voyager.php is like this ->

```
   'multilingual' => [
    /*
     * Set whether or not the multilingual is supported by the BREAD input.
     */
    'enabled' => true,

    /*
     * Set whether or not the admin layout default is RTL.
     */
    'rtl' => false,

    /*
     * Select default language
     */
    'default' => 'en',

    /*
     * Select languages that are supported.
     */
    'locales' => [
        'en',
        'pt',
    ],
],
```

I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684592/laravel-voyager-broken-strings-in-relationship-menu/53358400?noredirect=1#comment93593931_53358400) but without answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just created a new database and run again the `php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy` command.

Now the links appear to be normal!

Comment: Install it with dummy data, else you have to entry all them.

Answer (score -1):

This is a translate issue, just change in app.php:

```
'locale' => 'en'
```

to solve the issue. It worked for me.